# Can Kies provide a data connection so my phone can avoid mobile data usage?

Tags: usb, connection-sharing, kies

I regularly connect my Samsung phone by USB cable to my PC to charge it up, and when I run the Samsung Kies app on the PC I can sync data too. Is it possible for my phone to use my PCs internet connection through the USB link to avoid data charges?

I don't have a wifi connection available.

It would make sense if Kies could provide this, or perhaps there's some other way I can achieve it without wifi, such as using Bluetooth.

I have a Samsung GT-S7500, though this question should apply to many other models.